# How estimate the minimum size of an autoencoder to overfit the training data?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, autoencoders, overfitting, computational-learning-theory

Given e.g. $1$M vectors of $1000$ floating points each, where every point in vectors is sampled from a uniform distribution between $-1$ to $1$, how to estimate the minimum network size required between input ($1000$ units), bottleneck (preferably $1$ unit), and output ($1000$ units) which is cable of overfitting the training data perfectly?